# Eclipse Neon not launching on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, eclipse

[image: Stuck at mini launch screen]

As you can see from the picture, that's what I get whenever I open eclipse now. It used to work fine before, but ever since the latest Ubuntu updates, eclipse (Neon) gets stuck at that screen that I just showed you. Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have Openjdk8 or Oraclejdk8 on your system.
2. delete main eclipse folder and also these folders and files if you have:

   /usr/lib/eclipse/

   /usr/share/eclipse/

   /etc/eclipse.ini
3. Download Eclipse from eclipse.org and run it.